# PyOSC, python. Why oscserver needs IP address for receiving?

Tags: android, python, osc

In PyOSC, you need to both IP and port for the OSCServer to receive information. And this doesn't quite make sense to me. As on Max, you only need to declare the port. Isn't for receiving you always just need the localhost as the ip?

I have an android app which send OSC message to my python program on my computer. And trouble I have now is on Python I always need to enter the right IP of my computer in order for it to work. It won't even work if I change it to "localhost".

To my understanding, for udp receive, you only need to open up a port and IP is irrelevant because it is always going to be localhost.

```
class Rating_receiver:
    def __init__(self, ip = '192.168.0.3', port = 50010, num_emotion = 9, num_degree = 4):
        self.receive_address = ip, port
        self.num_emotion = num_emotion
        self.num_degree = num_degree
        self.choice = targetlist[0]
        self.degree = degreelist[0]

    def spawn(self):
        print"Server Created."
        self.receiveServer = OSC.OSCServer(self.receive_address) 
        self.receiveServer.addDefaultHandlers()

    def start(self):
        # Start OSCServer
        print "\nStarting OSCServer."
        self.emorating_oscServer = threading.Thread(target = self.receiveServer.serve_forever)
        self.emorating_oscServer.start()
        print "\nOSCServer established.

rating_receiver = Rating_receiver(ip = "localhost", port = 7110, num_emotion = 9, num_degree = 4)
rating_receiver.spawn()
```

So it won't work if I set ip to "localhost" (the server can be built but not able to receive any message), only work when I enter the actual IP, e.g. "192.168.0.3". 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `127.0.0.1` ? it should work everywhere.

I believe you are giving the IP the server will use.

- `127.0.0.1` basically means : "listen only for local connections".
- `192.168.0.3` (in your case) means : "listen for connections from the whole subnetwork"
- `0.0.0.0` means : "listen for connections from everywhere."

Comment: I did and unfortunately it doesn't work. My solution for now is using ipAddr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()) to get the ip. Maybe I can try 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use "localhost".

Define the port you want, and then send the messages from the other computer to the one running this code on its ip. I suppose you've already taken care of things such as port opening and you know about the difference of access scope from the outside network to inside your router, but I'll list it to make it clear:

- If you're sending messages from the same network, you don't need to worry about ports. Simply find the local ip for your computer. e.g. 192.168.X.XXX
- If you're sending messages from outside, open up the public port 50010 and redirect it to your inner ip 192.168.X.XXX on the same port 50010.

You have to define the "default_handler" function to handle the received messages, not sure if you defined it and forgot to show it here:

```
def default_handler(addr, tags, stuff, source):
        print "SERVER: No handler registered for ", addr
return None
```

You may also want to checkout an example for you OSCServer syntax.